# Can we use the sponge construct to efficiently authenticate any cipher?

Tags: authenticated-encryption, sponge

The sponge construct facilitates [authenticated encryption](http://sponge.noekeon.org/SpongeDuplex.pdf) independently of the 
function used to mix its state. Could we use any strong cipher (i.e. AES-256) as the
mixing function in a sponge to produce a fast authenticated encryption 
primitive? [This question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/20718/is-a-strong-block-cipher-usable-as-a-strong-sponge-function) indicates that using a block cipher in the context
of a mixing function for a sponge should be secure

Assume the interface of the sponge construct in question accepts a key and iv to provide to the underlying block cipher, so that the cipher can be used as otherwise intended.

The main consideration I see is that of the size of the capacity + rate 
compared to that of the cipher. Supposing the size of the rate and capacity
were equal to the blocksize of the cipher, well, it seems like that would
simply be too small? The security of a sponge appears to be related to it's
capacity, so using a 64 or 128 bit capacity makes me second guess the idea,
and even that would only leave 192 or 128 bits left for actual enciphering of
data.

I imagine a workaround as being enciphering the entire state as a message
under a standard mode of operation such as cbc, but I am unsure as to whether
or not there are problems with the idea. [This question seems to more or less address this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3200/hash-function-from-narrower-block-cipher-operated-in-cbc-encryption-mode), but will take me some time to totally understand due to the depth.

Comment: for a good sponge, you need at least a permutation that operates on 256 bits (or more preferably for a decent rate). You won't get this with the standard modes. You can however use something like [EME](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/24990/23623) (which would give you at most a 16kbit permutation) for this. The question then becomes: Is this faster than using a dedicated, unkeyed permutation?

Comment: you can build a permutation from an unkeyed AES round function very easily. arrange state in cube, 2x2x2, perform 2 AES rounds across each pair of vectors, and you have a 1024-bit nonlinear permutation